# How to define function in PHP

Tags: php, function

```
<?php
function array() {
    return array();
}
?>
```

The following function won't work. I get this error:

`Message : syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting T_STRING or '('`

Comment: `array` is a reserved word. Even if you could use that word, you would create an infinite loop.

Comment: Everything you'll need to know about defining a function in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: In addition to 'array' being a reserved word, this code will eventually cause a stack overflow since you're recursively calling your function to no end.

Comment: I would advice you to learn first, how functions work.

Comment: That is so stupid. I want to define the function named `array()` but can't.

Comment: It's not stupid. This convention has been used for decades. Maybe even before you were born. @user660943

Comment: Well to be honest @user660943 I tried it lot of time and later came to know its reserved after got the error ;)

Comment: And to add more if you dont get error meaning you never tried, and thats the best way to learn.... cheers !

Comment: As `Marc B` would say [`"RTFM"`](http://www.php.net/array) --- The `"F"` by the way, stands for `FABULOUS` ;-)

Comment: This question stems from lack of understanding of basic programming concepts and is not likely to be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 10):

You can't name a function `array`. It's reserved by the language.

Comment: ...by many programming languages, actually. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`Array` is a language construct (in other words it's not a function, it's a command to create a data structure). If it were simply a function you could override it but language constructs are reserved because they do specific things.

You can find the complete list of reserved words [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of function in PHP

```
function getFullName($firstname,$lastname){
 return $firstname.' '.$lastname;

}

echo getFullName('Abhik','Chakraborty');
```

The above will out put Abhik Chakraborty.

So the user defined functions can not be reserved key words as mentioned by others. So when you choose a function name make sure its not one of them.

The arguments in the functions must be in the function signature as

```
function getFullName($firstname,$lastname)
```

The function may or may not return any data depending on how you want to implement it. If we change the above function as

```
function getFullName($firstname,$lastname){
 echo $firstname.' '.$lastname;

}
```

And then do something like

```
getFullName('Abhik','Chakraborty');
```

this will out put as

Abhik Chakraborty.

You can learn more here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear first. Secondly you have used a language reserved  construct word. 
if you mean that you would like to use a function which returns php array.

you can try some thing like

```
function returnArray($assocArray = array()) {
    return $assocArray;
}
var_dump(returnArray(array('A'=> 1, 'B'=>2, 'C'=>3)));
```

or like this:

```
    function returnArray($assocArray = array('A'=> 'imik', 'B'=>2, 'C'=>3)) {
        return $assocArray;
    }

   foreach (returnArray() as $key=>$value){
    echo  " $key : $value <br/>";
   }
```